# Invalid field uid

Tags: control-panel, debugging

I keep seeing this in the craft debug bar in the control panel

Invalid field UID: 22faa4bf-2fb5-415b-b4e9-2416fe728843

How can I investigate what this means and resolve it?

UPDATE:
I've searched the fields table and layouts tbale for the uid and been thru PhpStorm project searches and it doesn't show up anywhere in the project logs/config.

Here is the stack trace

```
yii\base\InvalidArgumentException: Invalid field UID: 22faa4bf-2fb5-415b-b4e9-2416fe728843 in /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/fieldlayoutelements/CustomField.php:109
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/BaseObject.php(159): craft\fieldlayoutelements\CustomField->setFieldUid('22faa4bf-2fb5-4...')
#1 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(558): yii\base\BaseObject->__set('fieldUid', '22faa4bf-2fb5-4...')
#2 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/BaseObject.php(107): yii\BaseYii::configure(Object(craft\fieldlayoutelements\CustomField), Array)
#3 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/fieldlayoutelements/BaseField.php(59): yii\base\BaseObject->__construct(Array)
#4 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/fieldlayoutelements/CustomField.php(39): craft\fieldlayoutelements\BaseField->__construct(Array)
#5 [internal function]: craft\fieldlayoutelements\CustomField->__construct(NULL, Array)
#6 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(419): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)
#7 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(170): yii\di\Container->build('craft\\fieldlayo...', Array, Array)
#8 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(365): yii\di\Container->get('craft\\fieldlayo...', Array, Array)
#9 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/Craft.php(61): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Array, Array)
#10 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/Fields.php(1340): Craft::createObject(Array)
#11 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/models/FieldLayoutTab.php(141): craft\services\Fields->createLayoutElement(Array)
#12 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/BaseObject.php(109): craft\models\FieldLayoutTab->init()
#13 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/Fields.php(1225): yii\base\BaseObject->__construct(Array)
#14 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/Fields.php(1247): craft\services\Fields->_createLayoutTabFromRow(Array, true)
#15 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/Fields.php(1135): craft\services\Fields->_loadTabs(Array)
#16 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/Sections.php(1032): craft\services\Fields->getLayoutsByIds(Array)
#17 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/Sections.php(1009): craft\services\Sections->_entryTypes()
#18 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/models/Section.php(334): craft\services\Sections->getEntryTypesBySectionId(37)
#19 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/assets/cp/CpAsset.php(518): craft\models\Section->getEntryTypes()
#20 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/assets/cp/CpAsset.php(499): craft\web\assets\cp\CpAsset->_entryTypes(Object(craft\models\Section))
#21 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/assets/cp/CpAsset.php(373): craft\web\assets\cp\CpAsset->_publishableSections(Object(craft\elements\User))
#22 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/assets/cp/CpAsset.php(100): craft\web\assets\cp\CpAsset->_craftData()
#23 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/View.php(274): craft\web\assets\cpname\CpAsset->registerAssetFiles(Object(craft\web\View))
#24 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/View.php(1953): yii\web\View->registerAssetFiles('craft\\web\\asset...')
#25 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/View.php(272): craft\web\View->registerAssetFiles('craft\\web\\asset...')
#26 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/View.php(1953): yii\web\View->registerAssetFiles('verbb\\base\\asse...')
#27 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/View.php(272): craft\web\View->registerAssetFiles('verbb\\base\\asse...')
#28 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/View.php(1953): yii\web\View->registerAssetFiles('verbb\\iconpicke...')
#29 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/View.php(168): craft\web\View->registerAssetFiles('verbb\\iconpicke...')
#30 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/View.php(1161): yii\web\View->endBody()
#31 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/56/568a431c5389273bf2501ea26fe51d9659313197e375b8fd81f18fe76e75e287.php(102): craft\web\View->endBody()
#32 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(405): __TwigTemplate_b06f297580a96620ddc33c45b35d0cac2eace54c8e25618266c8056f0bfb069c->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#33 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(378): Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#34 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/41/4144a3f1a7a70c4eda99d48a48c6c9ff6015246edff28267f235f7b05ea9c0ca.php(56): Twig\Template->display(Array, Array)
#35 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(405): __TwigTemplate_345517481bee85cb217815bf276f85b3947944acdd6ab76e29f6acbcb6a4ec18->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#36 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(378): Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#37 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/b5/b5cc4b1504a9d4c93efb67efb076f10d665c926e68e357d38f06755412cd2d83.php(165): Twig\Template->display(Array, Array)
#38 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(405): __TwigTemplate_240f80d3e59f671ba92edcafb2bbf7713041fd42d1a9ba49b2479a60c6eb7e03->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#39 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(378): Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#40 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/50/5035e9af462f183270c876e7fd71abb068acd541f9bcc4ef95eab13f1b6d2353.php(49): Twig\Template->display(Array, Array)
#41 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(405): __TwigTemplate_80a606bc74b28e25753ba0d4dd38790cffeea1dc6e5f591d26dbac42cdfc1f55->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#42 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(378): Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#43 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(390): Twig\Template->display(Array)
#44 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/twig/twig/src/TemplateWrapper.php(45): Twig\Template->render(Array, Array)
#45 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/twig/twig/src/Environment.php(318): Twig\TemplateWrapper->render(Array)
#46 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/View.php(408): Twig\Environment->render('utilities/_inde...', Array)
#47 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/View.php(461): craft\web\View->renderTemplate('utilities/_inde...', Array)
#48 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Controller.php(201): craft\web\View->renderPageTemplate('utilities/_inde...', Array, 'cp')
#49 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/controllers/UtilitiesController.php(89): craft\web\Controller->renderTemplate('utilities/_inde...', Array)
#50 [internal function]: craft\controllers\UtilitiesController->actionShowUtility('system-report')
#51 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#52 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(178): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#53 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(552): yii\base\Controller->runAction('show-utility', Array)
#54 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(293): yii\base\Module->runAction('utilities/show-...', Array)
#55 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(103): craft\web\Application->runAction('utilities/show-...', Array)
#56 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(278): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#57 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(384): craft\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#58 /Users/name/sites/health-trust/craft/public_html/index.php(26): yii\base\Application->run()
#59 /Users/name/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/server.php(235): require('/Users/alanspar...')
#60 {main}
```

Comment: I'm seeing a similar error - let me know if you find out the cause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only place that message appears in the Craft CMS codebase is [here](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/f65480f0af7097bd851846c016e3bcd2b4d0c93b/src/fieldlayoutelements/CustomField.php#L106).

So, the most likely cause is that something (Craft itself or a plugin/custom module) is calling the `setFieldUid()` method on a `CustomField` instance (i.e. a custom field in a field layout), passing the UID for a field that doesn't actually exist in your database. I've never seen that happen, and it's difficult to say what the root cause could be.

Things to try:

- Clear your data caches and compiled templates
- Make sure project config is in sync
- Search for the "Invalid field UID" message in your log files (`storage/logs`) to hopefully determine the root cause
- Turn on `devMode` to hopefully make Craft throw up a stack trace
- Search for the `22faa4bf-2fb5-415b-b4e9-2416fe728843` UID in the `fields` database column. Is there a field with that UID or not?

Comment: Thx Mats. Ive updated the post with the stack trace, and synced project config, cleared caches, searched db. Its kinda of circular to search for the uid that doesn't exist. I might step thru plugins and turn off/uninstall. Any more ideas welcome.

Comment: @joomkit Try deleting the folder `storage/runtime/compiled_classes`

Comment: It turned out to be a field layout - very hard to find and only solved by editing UI/ db change rather than project files changes

Answer (score 2):

I had the same thing it was an old Entry Instructions field that was a Craft 2 plugin. Search for the invalid UID in your /config/project folder - that is where I located mine. It will show up in a field layout project config file and the file name and info in the file will tell you which entry type/field layout it is. If you go there and resave the entry type field layout, it will update your project config files and fix the problem.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks Chad! - Brian from Flannel